# wordpress plugins - ajax request processing internal url but returning error (NOT FOUND)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am doing ajax call from a javascript file in my plugin to a php file in my plugin itself. Calling like this :

I passed this variable into the js file

plugin_dir_url(**FILE**);

In the js file, I am doing ajax call using this url :

thatvariable+"myphp.php"

'thatvariable' refers to the plugin_dir_url(**FILE**) that is passed to js file from php file .

In my local wordpress , its working, but , in the original website with domain, it is processing the destination php file, but returning error saying that file is not found . Also, the console showing the url saying that its not found, but if I click that url , its working . 
 Did I miss any permissions ? What is the solution for this ?

Comment: can your please paste some code ? so that we can debug it

Answer (score 0):

As a shot in the dark it sounds like it could be a cross domain issue http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy check that the ajax call is to the same domain that your website is based.

Comment: The plugins is working on some wordpress sites and not working in some other wordpress sites. But, to the same domain, not to other domains .